# Create different image versions with carrierwave based on a column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Here is an example:

*app/models/book.rb*

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum kind: { magazine: 0, newspaper: 1 }
  mount_uploader :main_pic, BookMainPicUploader

  # ...

end
```

*app/uploaders/book_main_pic_uploader.rb*

```
class BookMainPicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/featured/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  version :normal do
    process resize_to_fill: [800, 400]
  end

  version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [400, 400]
  end

end
```

The above code would create both normal and square versions for each kind of books, but we want to generate the normal version for magazines only and the square version for newspapers only.

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to the `version` method the `if` conditional option.

```
class BookMainPicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/featured/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  version :normal, if: :is_magazine? do
    process resize_to_fill: [800, 400]
  end

  version :square, if: :is_newspaper? do
    process resize_to_fill: [400, 400]
  end

  private

  def is_magazine? picture
    model.magazine?
  end

  def is_newspaper? picture
    model.newspaper?
  end

end
```

Comment: I just found the answer in carrierwave's readme, but still thank you for the reply.